# script popup for android and iOS - for your device exist app, how?

Tags: android, ios, popup

I developed simple android and iOS app. 
I want when user is in my site (from mobile phone), to popup text with redirect to google play or apple store, "for your device is available android or iOS application".

My question is how to do that? 
Which script i can put in my website so when user surfing on my website from mobile device to popup information that exist mobile application for his device?

Thank you

Comment: Is this native app? If it is just use alert dialog for android. Otherwise javascript is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

The way I would do this, first find the mobile type using mobile agent and base on that  will redirect to the correct locations. e.g. putting the java scripts on top of your header page between

```
<head></head>

<script>
if( /iPhone|iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
window.location = "YOUR apple app url goes here";
} else if( /Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
window.location = "YOUR google play app url goes here";
}
</script>
```

Comment: I  don't want immediately to redirect to google play or apple store.It would be good if i have text "for your device is available android or iOS application" and then to show link to google play or apple store. How to do that? Thank you.

Comment: Instead having redirect using the line window.location = "YOUR apple app url goes here";, replace with the code to load a pop-up or transparent pop-up with the info you want have with the clickable link to go. if you want me to write you a example, I can help you but I am sure you know what need to be done now. hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, good idea. But how to cache that content? I mean when user say cancel to remember that he don't want that app, or when user download app, and later go again to my site, that don't have again pop up?

Comment: I am not able to answer about the cache but this link may helps http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/cache where you can store and get the saved data when ever you want it. Using that why can't you have a condition statement to control this?

Answer (score 2):

**For Iphone devices** 
you need to add this in head

`<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, app-argument=myURL">`

affiliate-data and app-argument is optional

**For Android Devices**
There is no native support for App Banners
You need to create yourself banner or use the jquery plugin [click here](https://github.com/jasny/jquery.smartbanner/zipball/master) to download

Here is the markup 
`<head>
    <!-- copy head -->
    <meta name="google-play-app" content="app-id=com.adianteventures.adianteapps.feliz_navidapp">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.smartbanner.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <!-- end copy head -->
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
    <!-- copy body -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.smartbanner.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $().smartbanner();
    </script>
    <!-- end copy body -->
  </body>`

Answer (score 0):

I have this code in my index.html

```
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) ) {
            if (document.cookie.indexOf('iphone_redirect=false') == -1) {
                if (confirm('for your device exist iphone app')) {
                    window.location = 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/....';
                }
            }
        }


        var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
        var isAndroid = ua.indexOf('android') > -1;
        if(isAndroid) {
            if (confirm('for your device exist iphone app')) { 
                window.location = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=...';
            }
        }
```

But i don't know how to make cookie to remember my answer. 
If user click "cancel" or "OK" to remember "cancel" or "OK" until user clean cache.

Do you have idea how to make cookie to remember answer?